# Is there a faster way to access a property member of a class using reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

I am currently using the following code to access the property of an object using reflection:

```
 Dim propInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo = myType.GetProperty(propName)
 Dim objValue As Object = propInfo.GetValue(myObject, Nothing)
```

I am having some issues with the speed since this type of code is being called many times and is causing some slowdown.

I have been looking into using Refelction.Emit or dynamic methods, but I am not sure exactly how to make use of them.

Background Information:
I am creating a list of a subset of the properties of the object, associating then with some meta information (such as if they can be loaded from the database or xml, if they are editable, can the user see them). This is for later consumption so we can write code such as :

```
foreach prop as BaseWrapper in graphNode.NodeProperties
    prop.LoadFromDataRow(dr)
next
```

The application makes heavy use of having access to this list. The problem is that on the initial load of a project, a larger number of objects are being created that make use of this, so for each object created it is looping through this code a number of times. I initially tried adding each property to the list manually, but this ran into problems with not everything being initialized at the correct time and some other issues.

If there is no other good way, then I may have to rethink some of the design and see what else can be done to improve the performance.

Comment: Can you state what the goal is? Maybe you shouldn't be using Reflection at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways you can go:

- Use [`Expression Trees`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). You can compile them to delegates and cache them for subsequent uses.
- Use [`Runtime C# Code Compilation`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/Run-Time_Code_Generation1.aspx).
- Don't go for this approach. Tell us what you want to achieve and someone could come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a method like the following to generate delegates that will obtain the property of the given object.

```
Public Shared Function CreateGetter(objectType As Type, name As String) As Func(Of Object, Object)
    Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object), "self")

    Dim expression = Expression.Convert(Expression.[Property](Expression.Convert(param, objectType), name), GetType(Object))

    Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of Object, Object))(expression, param).Compile()
End Function
```

You pass in the type of the object that defines the property as `objectType`, and the property name as `name`.  You will be handed back a `Func(Of Object, Object)` that will fetch the value of the property from the object you pass in, and return that value typed as `Object` (boxed if appropriate).

Note that this approach will only save time if you cache the delegate in a lookup like a `Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Object, Object))` for future reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VB-er but the CLR has to perform the lookup every time you do this (which is the bottleneck):

```
 Dim propInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo = myType.GetProperty(propName)
```

So try and cache the result of this in a static/shared variable and just call this separately:

```
 Dim objValue As Object = propInfo.GetValue(myObject, Nothing)
```

Comment: The `GetValue` call is also a bottleneck -- both operations are very slow compared to the corresponding JITed code that would fetch the property directly.